# How to import image (.svg, .png ) in a React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I am trying to import an image file in one of my react component. I have the project setup with web pack

Here's my code for the component

```
import Diamond from '../../assets/linux_logo.jpg';

 export class ItemCols extends Component {
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <section className="one-fourth" id="html">
                    <img src={Diamond} />
                </section>
            </div>
        )
    } 
}
```

Here's my project structure.

[image]

I have setup my webpack.config.js file in the following way

```
{
    test: /\.(jpg|png|svg)$/,
    loader: 'url-loader',
    options: {
      limit: 25000,
    },
},
{
    test: /\.(jpg|png|svg)$/,
    loader: 'file-loader',
    options: {
      name: '[path][name].[hash].[ext]',
    },
},
```

PS. I can get image from any other remote source but not locally saved images. The JavaScript Console also doesn't give me any error. Please anything helps. I am quite new to react and unable to find what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Shadid, did you try <img src={require('../../assets/linux_logo.jpg')} /> ?

Comment: yes I tried that. Again no error in the console but I see no image

Comment: You should do a webpack build and check where the images are stored. Use that path in img src.

Comment: @vijayst Bless you good sir.. That worked. :)

Comment: I've been struggling with this for hours. Why is it so hard to get a single logo image imported and looking right in React? It used to be so easy with plain HTML...

Answer (score 250, accepted):

try using

```
import mainLogo from'./logoWhite.png';

//then in the render function of Jsx insert the mainLogo variable

class NavBar extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <nav className="nav" style={nbStyle}>
        <div className="container">
          //right below here
          <img  src={mainLogo} style={nbStyle.logo} alt="fireSpot"/>
        </div>
      </nav>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What would happen if I want to import 10 images?

Comment: @LeoGasparrini - I'm not sure I understand what you're asking-- you should be able to import as many as you wish as long as you give them unique names at import, no?

Comment: I am trying the same approach and babel is complaining as it's not able to understand what a png file is. How can I let babel skip png files from transpiling?

Comment: I advise you use a create react app. Such issues are already pre solved with the setup. And you don't need to reengineer the process

Comment: is possible to re export from index.ts and access multiple image like this "import { image1, image2, image3} from './../images' "??

Comment: @AlexanderNied he is asking how to import multiple images to be used dynamically in a project.

Comment: For the curious minds out there, when we import an image like this, mainLogo is actually either a data URI (data:image/png;....) or a public URL (/static/logoWhite.svg) which dependss on your bundler.

Comment: what is nbstyle supposed to mean?

Comment: @Leo Gasparrini - your answers here, I suspect you found it by now:   https: //create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/

Answer (score 20):

You can use require as well to render images like

```
//then in the render function of Jsx insert the mainLogo variable

class NavBar extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <nav className="nav" style={nbStyle}>
        <div className="container">
          //right below here
          <img src={require('./logoWhite.png')} style={nbStyle.logo} alt="fireSpot"/>
        </div>
      </nav>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: When I tried this solution I got this error `[HMR] unexpected require(./src/components/LeftBar/home.svg) from disposed module ./src/components/LeftBar/LeftBar.js 
LeftBar
App@http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:115:79` Do you know whats happen? Thank You

Answer (score 13):

If the images are inside the src/assets folder you can use `require` with the correct path in the require statement,

```
var Diamond = require('../../assets/linux_logo.jpg');

 export class ItemCols extends Component {
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <section className="one-fourth" id="html">
                    <img src={Diamond} />
                </section>
            </div>
        )
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 7):

There are few steps if we dont use "create-react-app",(webpack@5.23.0)
first we should install file-loader as devDedepencie,next step is to add rule in webpack.config

```js
{
    test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
    loader: 'file-loader',
}
```

,
then in our src directory we should make file called declarationFiles.d.ts(for example) and register modules inside

```js
declare module '*.jpg';
declare module '*.png';
```

,then restart dev-server.
After these steps we can import and use images like in code bellow

```js
import React from 'react';
import image from './img1.png';
import './helloWorld.scss';

const HelloWorld = () => (
  <>
    <h1 className="main">React TypeScript Starter</h1>
        <img src={image} alt="some example image" />
  </>
);
export default HelloWorld;
```

Works in typescript and also in javacript,just change extension from .ts to .js

Cheers.

Comment: what abut path intellisense? how to get it work?

Answer (score 3):

You can also try:

```
...
var imageName = require('relative_path_of_image_from_component_file');
...
...

class XYZ extends Component {
    render(){
        return(
            ...
            <img src={imageName.default} alt="something"/>
            ...
        )
    }
}
...
```

Note: Make sure Image is not outside the project root folder.

Answer (score 3):

Create a folder and name it as `images.ts` or `images.js` in your assets folder or anywhere you wish.

Export all images in a folder using the `export {default as imageName} from 'route'` statement.

```
export { default as image1 } from "assets/images/1.png";
export { default as image2 } from "assets/images/2.png";
export { default as image3 } from "assets/images/3.png";
export { default as image4 } from "assets/images/4.png";
```

then import images using the `import {imageDefaultName} from 'route'`

```
import {image1,image2,image3,image4} from 'assets/images'

<img src={image1} />
<img src={image2} />
<img src={image3} />
<img src={image4} />
```

OR

```
import * as images from 'assets/images'

<img src={images.image1} />
<img src={images.image2} />
<img src={images.image3} />
<img src={images.image4} />
```

Comment: Cannot find module `"assets/images/1.png"` or its corresponding type declarations.

Comment: Did you save the image in `"assets/images/"` folder? 
You have to save the image your own project folder and then reference it from there.

Answer (score 2):

To dynamically import an image using a variable, you can use the following:

```
  const imageName = "myImage.png"
  const images = require.context('../images',true);
  const [imgUrl, setImgUrl] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    if (images && imageName) {
      setImgUrl(
        images(`./${imageName}`).default
      );
    }
  }, [imageName,images]);

  ...

  <img src={imgUrl} />
```

Answer (score 1):

I also had a similar requirement where I need to import .png images. I have stored these images in public folder. So the following approach worked for me.

```
<img src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + './Images/image1.png'} alt="Image1"></img>
```

In addition to the above I have tried using require as well and it also worked for me. I have included the images inside the Images folder in src directory.

```
<img src={require('./Images/image1.png')}  alt="Image1"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import imagename from './imagename.png'; //image is in the current folder where the App.js exits


class App extends React. Component{
    constructor(props){
     super(props)
     this.state={
      imagesrc=imagename // as it is imported
     }
   }

   render(){
       return (

        <ImageClass 
        src={this.state.imagesrc}
        />
       );
   }
}

class ImageClass extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return (

            <img src={this.props.src} height='200px' width='100px' />
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

I used [user5660307](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45387838/6200607) answer. And also for server-side rendering using react and nodejs, you can add this in express server:

`app.use(express.static("public"));`

and in webpack.client.js:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/client/client.js",

  output: {
    filename: "bundle.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "public"),
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      ...
      {
        loader: require.resolve("file-loader"),
        exclude: [/\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/, /\.html$/, /\.json$/],
        options: {
          name: "static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]",
        },
      },
      {
        test: [/\.bmp$/, /\.gif$/, /\.jpe?g$/, /\.png$/],
        loader: require.resolve("url-loader"),
        options: {
          name: "static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]",
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Answer (score -2):

Solved the problem, when moved the folder with the image in src folder. Then I turned to the image (project created through "create-react-app")
let image = document.createElement("img");
image.src = require('../assets/police.png');

Comment: Could be and so:
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class Lesson3 extends Component {
  render() {
        return (
           <image src={require('../assets/police.png')} />
        );
    }
}