# importing images locally in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am not understanding how import works in React. I'm currently using `create-react-app`. I have a folder inside components folder named `images`:

```
- src
  - components
    - images
```

Insides the components folder I also have a js file named `ProductSquare.js`.
I am trying to import a picture from images folder using this line

```
import bumper from './images/bumper1.png';
```

I have tried changing it to only `bumper1.png` and many other options. What am I doing wrong here? ( would appreciate a better way to do it in the future).

Is this how programmers import pictures in the real world?

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43823289/how-to-import-image-svg-png-in-a-react-component?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 2):

Try using `<img src={require('./images/bumper1.png')} />`

P.S.
The similar question goes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43823289/how-to-import-image-svg-png-in-a-react-component?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: yes that worked. Thank You so much. Why is it that you have to require it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using something like Webpack (which `create-react-app` does) then yes, you can just import the images (and most other file types). They end up getting converted into something (I believe images end up as a data URL).

If your folder structure looks like this:

- src

  - components
  - ProductSquare.js
  - images

Then you should be able to use the image like this:

```
// in ProductSquare.js
import React from 'react';
import bumper from './images/bumper1.png';

class ProductSquare extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <img src={ bumper } />;
  }
}
```

If it isn't, double-check that all of the files are named what you think they should be (check for typos and what not).

If everything is correct and it isn't working, try just adding `console.log(bumper)` before the class. Then:

- if it outputs a string that looks like `data:blahblah` it should work
- if it outputs undefined, the image may not be named properly
- if it doesn't output, you might not be using `ProductSquare` correctly

Comment: I found out that if I do this                                                                                                                                                                                                                  'const WPlogo = require('./images/logo.png');'
'  const bumper = require('./images/bumper1.png');'

Answer (score 1):

Using the `public` Folder

> Note: this feature is available with `react-scripts@0.5.0` and higher.

Create a folder in public folder, for example, 'image', add your photos there.

After that wherever you want you can use image address like this:

```
<img className="img1" src="/image/pic.jpg" alt=""/>
```

Answer (score 1):

> You Need to use .default after require

```
<img src={require('./images/bumper1.png').default} />
```