# Import assets without declaring

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I wanted to import image in react without declaring it on top of the file
like, `import img from './this/is/file.png'`

But, I wanted to import it directly to the jsx tag, how can I do that?

I've tried `<img src={import './this/is/file.png'} alt='' />` but it does not work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44154939/load-local-images-in-react-js, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50844727/importing-images-locally-in-react

Answer (score 0):

Use `require()`

```
<img src={require( './this/is/file.png')} alt='' />
```

Thinking about it though, I'm not sure the bundler (webpack?) will know what to do with this. There is also the potential for dynamic imports to help.