# React Image not recognizing file path when passing data from parent component to child component

Tags: reactjs

When I'm passing the img src address to the child component and try to render the image, I keep getting an error which is

> Error: Cannot find module './Assets/man-user.png'

this is the code for the parent component:

```
import React from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import {Icon} from './icons';

export class Body extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {img :"./Assets/man-user.png", name : "About Me",alt : "profile"}
}   
render(){
    return <Icon img = {this.state.img} name = {this.state.name} alt = {this.state.alt}/>
};
}
```

Code for the child component

```
import React from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';

const styles = {
    width : 310,
    height: 310,
    border: "solid black 5px",
    borderRadius: 83
};

export class Icon extends React.Component{

constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {name : '', open : 'false'};
};  

render(){
    return(
    <div style = {styles}>
        <img src =  {require(this.props.img)} alt = {this.props.alt}/>
        <h4>{this.props.name}</h4>
    </div>
    )}
 }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43823289/how-to-import-image-svg-png-in-a-react-component

Comment: Having the path to an image file in `state` would not have the image data in it. So when passed as props this path may or may not be the same for child components. 
`import Manuser from './Assets/man-user.png';` and then store it state something like `this.state= {img: Manuser}`. Passing this as `state` should work. 
Give it a try.

Comment: Thank you, the problem has been resolved