# uploading image in python flask server and display image in react frontend

Tags: python, reactjs, image, flask, display

I want to upload images to the server by using python flask in a fixed location by using the following code.

```
UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'F:\Coursera\React_Flask\SocialNetwork\Frontend\Api'
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
_file = request.files['file']
filename = secure_filename(_file.filename)
target = os.path.join(UPLOAD_FOLDER, 'image')
if not os.path.isdir(target):
                os.mkdir(target)
source = "/".join([target, filename])
_file.save(source)
```

Image is uploaded the corresponding folder. Then I try to display the image in react frontend by the following way but nothing display.

```
<img src={'../../../api/image/imagename.jpg'} alt='profile' />
```

folder structure: main directory:

```
F:\Coursera\React_Flask\SocialNetwork\Frontend\
 --api:
   -image  //images in this folder
   -venv
   -user_api.py  //flask api
 --node_modules
 --public
 --src:
    -components
       -profile
         -profilepage.js //react component.
```

Comment: make sure the images are in `src` folder ... not outside and follow this link [importing .png in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43823289/how-to-import-image-svg-png-in-a-react-component)

Comment: If I put the image in the src folder that is working. But in production, I provide only the build file and I want to upload images outside the build folder using the flask server and display images in react. In this case, I balance the folder structure. What can I do in that case? Is it possible? Any suggestions?

Comment: May be you should be using absolute path .. try that

Comment: `<img src={'F:/Coursera/React_Flask/SocialNetwork/frontend/api/image/garden-festival.jpg'} alt='profile' />` This is also not working.

Comment: I think you should refer this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44114436/the-create-react-app-imports-restriction-outside-of-src-directory#:~:text=jpg%20which%20falls%20outside%20of,to%20it%20from%20project's%20node_modules%2F.)