# How to import image from external folders in react

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs

am  a newbie in react and want to import an image from outside the root folder of project but react is not allowing me and i know can put those images inside public folder and can easily import them but only want to import them from outside directories

Comment: Is this your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43823289/how-to-import-image-svg-png-in-a-react-component

Answer (score 1):

You can not access outside the root folder in production, because your project is in the root directory of the server

if you want to access that file you create a virtual server that have access to that folder   then you easily can access the img :

```
   <img src={"localhost:8080/img.png"} />
```

If you tell us more maybe we can give you another solution.

Edit :
this is not just about images you do not have access to anything out of root directory using `import` or `require`