# Can't display images from local server on react js

Tags: reactjs, image, jsx, multer, src

Hello i am working on a Mern stack project where i have posts and each post has its image. In the back-end i am using multer to upload images to a directory i called uploads and everything works fine but when i want to display these images in my react js app it doesn't display the image . To do so i initialize a variable with this url

```
imagePath = "http://localhost:3000/"
```

then i concat this url with the path i stored in my database so my code look like this:

```
 {allPosts?.map((post) => {
           
          const image = imagesPath + post.image;
          return (
            <Post
              profilePicture={profileImge}
              dislikeCount={post.nbDislikes}
              downloadCount={post.nbDownloads}
              likeCount={post.nbLikes}
              postImage={image}
              postText={post.text}
              time="1 hour ago"
              username="John Doe"
              shareCount={post.nbShares}
               
            />
          );
        })}
```

and i try to display it like this in the Post component

```
      <img
          src={postImage}
          alt="LandingPageImage1"
          className="w-[80%]  object-fill md:h-[300px] mt-2 max-w-[90%]"
        />
```

but nothing is displayed even if i put in src the hole path like this :
http://localhost:3000/uploads/image.png
I searched a lot and tried so many things for example i can't use import to get the image since i pass the pass in the props, i tried require also but the same problem .
The most thing that is confusing me that when i put the same path in the browser url bar it displays the image so can anyone help me please ?

Comment: Your question has been answered already: [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43823289/how-to-import-image-svg-png-in-a-react-component)

Comment: I mentioned in my question that i can't use import since i am passing the image absolute path as a prop

Comment: Did you resolve your problem ? i have the same one